# flames slowly die out propane town and country

Tags: fireplace

I have a town and country TC 30. It is about 10 years old. It works off a remote maestro control that came with the unit. I keep the pilot light lit. Recently when the fire is started, it burns beautifully for about 30 minutes and then the flames slowly recede and eventually all that is left burning is the pilot light. The pilot light then seems to cycle getting slightly bigger and smaller but staying lit.After about 90 minutes the fire can be re-lit but the same outcome occurs.It is almost like the firebox is getting too hot and the system is shutting itself down.The cycling of the pilot light seems very odd.Do you have any thoughts?

Comment: does the unit have a sleep function of some type where is shuts down after a delay? ... it would be for use in a bedroom at bedtime

Comment: You might check and clean the flame sensor and area around it. See the user manual.

Comment: Is this from a propane tank, and is the tank unusually cold? And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.